# Android store the data without sheredprefarances ,database and file system

Tags: android, arraylist, storage

I want to know which way i can store the data? I want to store the **Array list** (bind with String) dynamically. where object contain all type of data like date,String,Boolean etc

1) **DataBase** : i can't use database because as per the project requirement we couldn't use database.

2) **sheredprefarance** : it generally used for store the small object but here the data is large so this option create cache memory issues.(not recommended for large data)

3) **file** : i used earlier but some feature not supported in android 2.3 or later. like Array list< object > was not stored because the array list contain some date format so it not converted into decimal format cause illegal argument exception.

please suggest me which way i store the data. thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you use internet?

Comment: yes,i find lots of solution from it and tried also. i succeeded in some of them but due to version compatibility and some other issue i couldn't get succeed.

Comment: I suppose you tried with JsonReader because of the size of the input when you mean version compatibility? If yes, you can use GSON by Google, it has a streaming capability. If this is not the problem, can you explain in more details why exactly does the Internet not work for you?

Comment: You could write an api in php or any other script and store it in server.

Comment: If the data you want to store change frequently or is very large, the best way to do so will be with SQLlite and Transactions, why can't you use Databases?

Comment: @YordanLyubenov i am new to android i tried almost solution which i know to use for it. due to less experience and knowledge, i don't know more way to store the data. so just lake of knowledge i was not search for that solution.

Comment: @AssafG. i explained in question, why i can't use database?

Comment: @MayurRaval What is considered a Database? SharedPref. in it's way is a database, it's a database of key - value stored as XML file. What was the project requirement that forbids database usage?

Comment: @AssafG. yes i know shared preference is database in it's way .but it should use for store the small variable. and here the data is to large. Our project is on totally network we get the data from server and show it in application through json parsing.client -server data passing.

Comment: @MayurRaval and the data you get needs to be persistent between activities or between application restart?

Comment: @AssafG. oh.yes data should be persistent between activities or between application restart.

Comment: @MayurRaval Then good luck to you sir.

Answer (score 0):

make temp array list like JSON array list and store all data in this array list. As your requirement you can retrieve your data from this Array List

Comment: How exactly is that helping him?